# How do I assign a JSON Schema to a YAML file in my VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, jsonschema

I am writing a CLI tool that will have a fairly complex YAML configuration, so I wanted to create a VS Code extension to support that with completion provided by the JSON Schema and some snippets, but it seems not to work. I thought it would be useful to define a custom extension ".lake" for my config file.

This is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "lake-config",
  "displayName": "Lake Configuration Helper",
  "publisher": "essay97",
  "description": "Provides schema validation and snippets to configure Lake",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.80.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [],
  "main": "./extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "languages": [
      {
        "id": "yaml",
        "extensions": [
          ".lake"
        ],
        "aliases": [
          "Lake Config"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "jsonValidation": [
      {
        "fileMatch": "**/*.lake",
        "url": "./lake-schema.json"
      }
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "test": "node ./test/runTest.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/vscode": "^1.84.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.3",
    "@types/node": "18.x",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "glob": "^10.3.10",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.3.6"
  }
}
```

When I try to open an extension development host with F5 and open a .lake file, I get the YAML syntax highlighting, but not the JSON Schema, the bottom bar says "no json schema".

What am I missing? I even tried to set the `jsonValidation.url` to a random JSON schema from the internet to make sure it was not a problem in my schema but it's still not working.

Also: I'm not sure if I should depend on `redhat.vscode-yaml`. extension and what `extensionDependencies` does exactly.

Comment: if you have a `main` property you must have some `activationEvents`

Comment: is your `lake-schema.json` located in the root of the extension installation directory? https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.jsonValidation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding out that since the file I am trying to validate is YAML, it is handled by the YAML extension. In oreder to make it work I added to the package.json the `yamlValidation` block inside the `contributes`. The syntax is the exact same of `jsonValidation`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an extension based on [Red Hat's YAML Language Server](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml) such as [`redhat.vscode-yaml`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml), then use the `yamlValidation` contribution point. The contribution point in the extension manifest has the same shape as [VS Code's builtin `jsonValidation` contribution point](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.jsonValidation).

The relevant issue ticket which tracked this feature is [Consider providing a 'yamlValidation' contribution point for registering a schema #37](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml/issues/37). The feature was implemented by [commit `9fdaa7f`](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml/commit/9fdaa7f62f336def2d425f33ff6599db09c80f28) and released in [version 0.0.3](https://github.com/redhat-developer/yaml-language-server/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#003).